# The iOS system sound ID for the sms_alert_note.caf

Tags: ios

I want the system sound id for the system sounds located in this directory: http://onj3.andrelouis.com/phonetones/unzipped/Apple-iOS10/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/

I tried to find it here: https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices, but there is not any system sound listed from the /uisounds/modern

Can someone tell me how to find ID for sms_alert_note.caf

Answer (score 0):

In case of `sms_alert_note.caf` you can use path to this sound. In [this](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) repository you have description how to use that one.